# ffmpeg compile for Android

Tags: android, compiler-errors, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile ffmmpeg for android using [this](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg) but I'm getting " ERROR: freetype2 not found" as shown below in details.

```
linux@user1:~/Downloads/android-ffmpeg$ ./configure_ffmpeg.sh
~/Downloads/android-ffmpeg ~/Downloads/android-ffmpeg
No NDK_BASE set, using /opt/android-ndk
patching file ffmpeg/libavfilter/Makefile
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
The next patch would create the file ffmpeg/libavfilter/af_aredact.c,
which already exists!  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file ffmpeg/libavfilter/allfilters.c
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
The next patch would create the file ffmpeg/libavfilter/vf_redact.c,
which already exists!  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file ffmpeg/libavutil/arm/intmath.h
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
patching file libavcodec/arm/ac3dsp_armv6.S
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file libavcodec/arm/fft_fixed_neon.S
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file libavcodec/arm/fft_neon.S
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
patching file libavcodec/arm/sbrdsp_neon.S
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
patching file libavcodec/arm/vp3dsp_neon.S
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file libavcodec/arm/vp8_armv6.S
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
patching file libavcodec/arm/asm.S
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
patching file libavutil/arm/intmath.h
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
patching file configure
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
~/Downloads/android-ffmpeg/ffmpeg ~/Downloads/android-ffmpeg ~/Downloads/android-ffmpeg
*****************The error is here*****************

ERROR: freetype2 not found

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
```

I have freetype installed and I also linked it as shown below in the /usr/include/

```
rwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Mar 20 22:13 freetype2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     23 Mar 20 22:14 freetype -> /usr/include/freetype2/
```

I'm not sure what to do next, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You need a version of freetype2 which has been built for ARM, and likely the freetype2 installed under /usr/include is built for the architecture of your PC. It looks like that project includes a configure script for building freetype2 for ARM. This should work if you use that script to build freetype2 and link to that version instead.